# Android Studio (kotlin) problems with string-array from R

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem with my import R.
I have the line import android.R, it's ok
in this line my program does not recognises the types name array. My line is that

```
val typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

I have and xml created named arrays.xml with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="types">
        <item>Credito</item>
        <item>Debito</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

so my app should recognise my R.arraytypes but it does not.
The error is:

```
Unresolved reference: types
```

I searched for a solution and I read someone write a solution could be to the delete the import android.R but when I do, I have a problem with this too:

```
val cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cities)
```

it marks me simple_spinner_dropdown_item in red.
So IDK what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, you reference resources from different R classes, so there is a namespace conflicts. To resolve it, you should specify each of them:

```
val typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, your.package.name.R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

As well, you can move one of it to import statement, for example:

```
import your.package.name
val typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

Comment: ty very much! It works for me the line:

val typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, com.example.spinners.R.array.types, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

Answer (score 1):

First of all invalidate caches and clean project and then add your package name and then R along with it.